# Surfaceview with admob

Tags: java, android, admob, android-relativelayout

Im trying to create a game. Im using a Surfaceview to draw on, and now I would like an admob view to show up at the buttom of the screen. I have tried to create a RelativeLayout programtically, but currently the **only view to be shown is the surfaceview**, the admob view is not shown!

This is the code:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    AdView admobView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "MY_ADMOB_ID");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams admobParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    admobParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM);

    admobView.setLayoutParams(admobParams);

    layout.addView(admobView);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams threadParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    threadParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

    admobView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    TimermodeThread timerThread = new TimermodeThread(getApplicationContext());
    timerThread.setLayoutParams(threadParams);
    layout.addView(timerThread);

    setContentView(layout);
```

Is there anyone who could help me?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I can see in Log that I have recieved the ad. So, im guessing the surfaceview is taking all the space!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your surface view is taking up the whole screen. instead of using the relative layout use Framelayout. and add the code for layouting the ad at the end.